# Intermittent VBA macro error

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below code to cycle through my worksheets as a kind of slideshow to use in a sales department. The code works perfectly when I step through in debug mode, however when I run the macro it only works intermittently, occasionally getting to the selecting of the worksheets without having reactivated the screen updating application function.

Here is the code I have created so far:

```
Sub Runshow()

Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo exit_
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Protect
Next

Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Let y = 0
Do Until y = 80

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open("c:\users\admin\downloads\crm.xlsx").Activate
    Application.Calculate

    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Let x = 0
    Do Until x = 23

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Select
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
            x = x + 1
        Next

    Loop

    y = y + 1
Loop

exit_:

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect
Next

Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also your loop for `Do Until x = 23` doesn't seem to be doing anything? You're looping through each workbook then repeating this loop 23 times, yet never using x for anything. Also what is your reason for `y = y + 1` twice in the same loop, can't you just use `y = y + 2` once? And i dont see what the `y` loop is for.

Comment: I didn't realize you can use `Let` in VBA.  Thanks for your question, taught me something!

Comment: Why not use powerpoint?

Comment: Tim - My logic behind the x loop is to have the code run through all sheets 23 times consecutively before the y loop opens an external workbook to update the data. will this not achieve the desired result?

Comment: BruceWayne - No problem, happy that I have bestowed knowledge from my limited understanding :)

Comment: Findwindow - My knowledge of PowerPoint is very limited, is it possible to display excel data in a Powerpoint slideshow and if so, are you able to provide a link to a help guide?

Comment: Tim - Also I must apologise, the `y = y + 1` being included twice was an error on my part. Have amended the code above to reflect. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together some simple code that does something similar, and works well. You can build out from here - ask any questions if there's anything you don't understand.

```
Sub Slideshow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    PrepareView True

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    Next ws

    PrepareView False
End Sub

Function PrepareView(status As Boolean)
    If status = True Then
        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
    ElseIf status = False Then
        Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this Callum, it looks great! gives me an insight into the creation of functions also.

Comment: Hi @Boovda. Pleased to help. If you found that this answered your question please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of this answer.